# Array Initialization Riddle Java

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I have this code:

```
int[] copyFrom = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int[] copyTo   = new int[9];
copyTo = copyFrom;
copyFrom = new int[9];
System.out.println(copyTo[0]);
```

The value I get is "1"..

To my understanding copyTo=copyFrom copies just the reference to the array.
So why when I initialize copyFrom, copyTo still refers to the old memory?

Apologies if this is dumb or duplicate, I am a novice user.

Comment: You may want to pick up a book on Java and read about memory addressing. You will have many many more questions.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. You are again initializing copyFrom with another object, then how still will point to the previous object. Think with a common sense you will realize the situation.

Comment: @ObedMarsh The question is valid (=no close vote), yet bad (=downvote). It is (as the tooltip for downvotes say: "does not show any research efford") not researched.

Comment: @ObedMarsh not "idiot" but person who either thinks that (1) OP didn't do his/her research, (2) question is unclear, or (3) question is not useful. I suspect that vote was cast because of 1st point.

Comment: @Pshemo I don't mind at all the downvotes on my question. I understand this is a novice question.. After all I apologized in advance.

However, with my very limited knowledge of Java, I found it interesting.. Apologies if I have wasted your time, but I was hoping to get some more in-depth views on the memory management issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what is happening:

```
int[] copyFrom = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int[] copyTo   = new int[9];
```

can be visualized as

```
copyFrom ------------> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

copyTo   ------------> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Now `copyTo = copyFrom;` makes `copyTo` hold same value as `copyFrom` so new situation looks like

```
copyFrom ---------+
                  |
                  +--> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
                  |
copyTo   ---------+
```

As you see there are still two references, but they just hold same value so changing one of them can't affect other (I am talking about changing value of references - `ref = new Value();` - not state of object they hold `ref.setParam(foo);`)

Then you change `copyFrom` reference to hold new array `copyFrom = new int[9];` so now you have

```
copyFrom ------------> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

copyTo   ------------> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

That is why `System.out.println(copyTo[0]);` prints `1`.

Comment: Great.. Thank you for the very elaborate answer.
That was indeed my suspicion.
However I couldn't quite accept this memory management issue in Java.
It's like the second reference is refering to an obsolete memory address. If I initialized both references, would it clear the memory?..

Again, apologies for the ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

let's put in this way:

```
int[] copyFrom = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; //cpFrom holds memory addr 123 to the array
int[] copyTo   = new int[9]; //cpTo holds addr 456 to a new array
copyTo = copyFrom; //now cpTo and cpFrom hold same addr 123
copyFrom = new int[9]; //now cpFrom holds addr 789(new arr), but cpTo still holds 123
```

now you see

Answer (score 0):

```
1- copyFrom -> array1 = {1,2..9}
2- copyTo -> array2 = new int[]
3- copyTo -> array1 (array2 is lost)
3- copyFrom -> array3 = new int[]
```

So in the end, copyTo points to the first array, hence the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You copy the reference to a memory location containing the data `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`.
Then when you initializes copyFrom, it refers to a new memory location, while copyTo still refers to the first memory location.

Answer (score 0):

When you do copyTo = copyFrom; in 3rd line. copyTo points to the array at line 1 i.e copyFrom. and in next line you are pointing copyFrom to a new array.copyTo array still points to array at line 1 and when you print copyTo[0] ,it picks the first element of the array it is pointing to. Hence the answer 1.

Hope it clarifies.